# Размещение сайта ASP.net в домен на сервере IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis

Есть сайта ASP.net размещенный на сервере IIS , он запускается : localhost с портом 443

У меня есть доменное имя, предположим "somesite.ru".
Я в сервере iis захожу в привязки-> добавить и вот как добавляю, после чего, соответственно он не работает..Пишет: не удается получить доступ к сайту. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем заключается `он не работает`, вы нам конечно не скажете...

Comment: Пишет: не удается получить доступ к сайту

Comment: мало информация. откуда куда заходите? а какое поведение желаете? Если у вас один сайт на ip, можно не указывать имя узла и убрать галочку вовсе

Comment: Открыт ли порт? Сертификат самоподписан? Если последнее да - тогда ошибка будет в доверии к сертификату